# Polluted well water: binomial distribution problem.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

My probability textbook presents the following example problem on binomial distributions:

> It is conjectured that an impurity exists in $30$% of all drinking wells in a certain
> rural community. In order to gain some insight into the true extent of the problem,
> it is determined that some testing is necessary. It is too expensive to test all of the
> wells in the area, so 10 are randomly selected for testing.

And one of the questions asks:

> The notion that 30% of the wells are impure
> is merely a conjecture put forth by the area water board. Suppose 10 wells are
> randomly selected and 6 are found to contain the impurity. What does this imply
> about the conjecture? Use a probability statement.

I solved this problem on my own by calculating the probability that $6$ wells are found to contain the impurity. Let $X$ denote the number of impure wells found. Then:

$P(X=6)=b(6; 10, 0.3) =$ $10 \choose 6$ $(0.3)^6(0.7)^4=0.0368 = 3.68\%$

So this is how I interpret this result:

> If we assume the conjecture is in fact correct, then it would imply that the probability of finding $6$ wells that are impure out of a random sample of $10$ is only $3.68\%$, which is quite low. This suggests the conjecture is inaccurate.

Here is how they approached the problem:

[image]

Here's what I'm wondering: why did they choose to consider the probability that $X \geq 6$?

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to assess whether or not having $6$ impure wells is believable, under the assumption that the actually proportion is $30$%.  If having $6$ impure wells were hard to believe, then having more than $6$ would be even harder.  So one should count the probability of $6$ or more, not just $6$.

Perhaps it will help if you consider another example which illustrates the issue with only calculating the probability of one specific value: I want to know whether I should believe that a coin is fair.  So I assume it is fair, toss it $1000$ times, and observe that it comes up heads $500$ times.  Under the assumption of fairness, I calculate that the probability of this outcome is $0.025$.  This is very small, so I do not believe the coin is fair.

The conclusion is clearly wrong!  I hope this illustrates the problems that may arise with calculating probabilities for single outcomes only.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm still a bit skeptical about this (though I don't doubt this is true). I find it odd that $P(X=500)$ is $2.5\%$ (I checked myself, and you're right). I would think it would be closer to $0.5$, if not $0.5$ itself.

Comment: The point with the coin example is that there are $1001$ possible outcomes and each of them is individually unlikely.  Obtaining $500$ heads is "the most likely", but it is not "very likely".  Analogy: sharing a million dollars with your friends might make you rich - but not if you have a million friends :)

Comment: Sorry, not sure I followed your analogy :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the well-known procedure for a **hypothesis test**. You are trying to determine if the value $X=6$ lies in the **critical region** (usually defined as the upper or lower $5$% of the distribution). You can determine this to be the case in this example if $p(X\geq6)<0.05$ which is true.

We conclude therefore that there is evidence that the percentage of polluted wells is greater than $30$% at the "$5$% level" of significance.

The individual probability $p(X=6)$ is of no importance. However the occurrence of 6 polluted wells in the sample can be regarded as very unlikely if the proportion is only $30$%.